# Only want to compare TIME values MomentJS

Tags: javascript, momentjs

After looking through some of the other MomentJS Questions and answers I'm still stumped as to how one would use moment to simply compare **two different times**.

I do not need (want) the day/date to be considered.

My use case is this:
    I'm reading a schedule (start/end times) from a config file.  This is done using Node.js

> Starttime = 6:30 PM
>   Endtime = 3:30 AM

```
var currentTime= moment();    // e.g. 11:00 pm
var starttime = moment('06:30 pm', "HH:mm a");
var endtime = moment('03:30 am', "HH:mm a");

amIBetween = currtime.isBetween(starttime , endtime);
console.log(amIBetween);   //  returns false
```

My scenario is technically spanning two days and I understand why it's false.

I need (expect) moment to return TRUE - i.e. that currtime isBeteen start and endtime and falls in that range.

Would I need to check for a time after 12AM and then add a day to make the check work?
Any other suggestions for accomplishing this. I looked at moment-range which has 'contains ' function but with similar question for that.

I'm finding it hard to believe that it's this complex, but maybe it is :\

--

Here's further clarification that issue arises with spanning days, even when trying to be more explicit:

```
var currentTime= moment('11:00p', "HH:mm a");
var startTime = moment('06:00p', "HH:mm a");
var endTime = moment('03:30a', "HH:mm a");

currentTime.toString(); //"Fri Oct 28 2016 23:00:00 GMT-0400"
startTime.toString();   // "Fri Oct 28 2016 18:00:00 GMT-0400"
endTime.toString();    // "Fri Oct 28 2016 03:30:00 GMT-0400"

currentTime.isBetween(startTime, endTime);  // false
currentTime.isAfter(endTime) && currentTime.isBefore(startTime); //false
currentTime.isAfter(startTime) && currentTime.isBefore(endTime); //false
```

Seems kind of obvious that they'd be false since the *day/date* is considered by moment.  This is what I'm trying to get around.

The following would work:

```
endTime.add(1, "days");
currentTime.isBetween(startTime, endTime);  // TRUE
```

This would mean however, that I'd need to check if the START TIME was before 12AM && the ENDTIME as after 12AM then add 1 day to ENDTIME.  Kludge?

Answer (score 4):

After my own testing and looking at other's suggestions it sill appeared that disregarding DAY/DATE and trying to span days was an issue.  I came up with this which is now working in my app.

```
isTimeBetween = function(aStartTime, anEndTime, aCurrTime)
{
    // you may pass in aCurrTime or use the *actual* current time
    var currentTime = !aCurrTime ? moment() : moment(aCurrTime, "HH:mm a");
    var startTime = moment(aStartTime, "HH:mm a");
    var endTime = moment(anEndTime, "HH:mm a");

    if (startTime.hour() >=12 && endTime.hour() <=12 )
    {
        endTime.add(1, "days");       // handle spanning days
    }

    var isBetween = currentTime.isBetween(startTime, endTime);

    /***  testing   
    startTimeString = startTime.toString();
    endTimeString = endTime.toString();
    currentTimeString = currentTime.toString();

    console.log(startTimeString);
    console.log(endTimeString);
    console.log(currentTimeString);
    console.log('\nis '+ currentTimeString  + ' between ' + 
              startTimeString + ' and ' + endTimeString + ' : ' 
              + isBetween);
    ****/
    return isBetween;
    }

isTimeBetween("06:30pm", "03:30am", "11:00pm");     //true      !! this is main use case
isTimeBetween("06:30pm", "10:30pm", "11:00pm");     //false
isTimeBetween("04:00am", "06:00am");                //true (e.g. current time is 5am
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues.

1) Your variable name `currtime` on line 5 is different than your declaration on line 1 `currentTime`

2) You could break it up into two checks around midnight like so:

```
var currentTime = moment();    // e.g. 11:00 pm
var sixThirty = moment('06:30 pm', "HH:mm a");
var midnight = moment('12:00 am', "HH:mm a");
var threeThirty = moment('03:30 am', "HH:mm a");

amIBetween1 = currentTime.isBetween(sixThirty , midnight);
amIBetween2 = currentTime.isBetween(midnight , threeThirty);
console.log(amIBetween1);
console.log(amIBetween2);
```

Comment: Yeah, that was typo on currtime.  Appreciate the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

dylpickle's answer looks correct to me, but if you decide that the isBetween is easy to fumble, then you may want to take that abstraction away, take a step down into it's functionality.

**"explicitness is far cheaper than the wrong abstraction"**

That is not to say that isBetween is the wrong abstraction, but it is a tiny bit less explicit in that you could easily feed it the parameters in the wrong answer which would give you the opposite of what you intended.

If you

```
console.log(currentTime.isBetween)
```

you get the implementation:

```
ob(a,b,c,d){return d=d||"()",("("===d[0]?this.isAfter(a,c):!this.isBefore(a,c))&&(")"===d[1]?this.isBefore(b,c):!this.isAfter(b,c))}
```

Notice that it just uses **isAfter()** and **isBefore()**.
Sometimes you can simplify things sometimes by being more explicit with your code.

isBetween looks a little uglified and seems to cover all of the edge cases, but don't be afraid to try to improve things either.

Try the following code:

```
const isBetween = currentTime.isAfter(endtime) && currentTime.isBefore(starttime);

console.log(isBetween)
```

There is no way to get confused in the implementation or adding changes later. This does not increase cyclomatic complexity or lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and I did a kind of work around as follows:

```
function fgEsHora1MayorAHora2(hora1, hora2) {

  var f1 = moment('2000-01-01 ' + hora1);
  f1.tz('America/Mexico_City').format('ha z');
  let f1Hora = f1.toObject().hours;
  let f1Minutos = f1.toObject().minutes;

  var f2 = moment('2000-01-01 ' + hora2);
  f2.tz('America/Mexico_City').format('ha z');
  let f2Hora = f2.toObject().hours;
  let f2Minutos = f2.toObject().minutes;

  let minutos1 = parseInt(f1Hora * 100) + parseInt(f1Minutos);
  let minutos2 = parseInt(f2Hora * 100) + parseInt(f2Minutos);

  return minutos1 > minutos2;
}
```

I separated the hours and multiply it by 100 in order to give it more value... so, I added "hours" plus minutes and then I did the comparison..

Remarks: The trick stands on add the date like **"2001-01-01"**, just to be able to get the time and hour...

And it's working fine!!